# 23 bit user defined type in c++

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I was wondering if it is possible to create a 23-bit user defined type in c++. I can create a 24-bit type just fine using 3 chars however I am trying to get one bit less. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always use 3 chars (or even just a int32_t) to store your type in -- do you have requirements that make such an approach inadequate? If so, it would help if you explicitly stated those requirements.

Comment: Perhaps [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is what you're looking for, but maybe it isn't.

Comment: You issue is that the platform will store the bits in the most convenient unit it has.  For example, if your platform is 7-bits, you will still need to use 28-bit or 4 units, because the platform can't store bits individually.

Comment: You cannot create a type whose representation is exactly 23 bits in size.  You *can* create a type whose representation is larger, but of which you use only 23 bits.

Comment: It would be possible if you compiled for a system where `CHAR_BIT` is 23.

Comment: What about if you used 23 bools? (the memory will still be padded for 32 or 64 bits)

Comment: @Ben - Cringe.  I've seen people do this and get the infamous 1,000,000 size array of 32-bit bools before.  Oh the wasted space :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: `vector<bool>` is supposed to be implemented as a bit-vector under the covers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a bit-field.

```
struct TwentyThreeBits {
    int x : 23;

    TwentryThreeBits & operator = (int y) {
        x = y;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This allows you manipulate the member `x` as a 23 bit value. The actual size of the type is likely larger (likely `sizeof(TwentyThreeBits)` is at least `sizeof(int)`).

If you would like to represent many items that only occupy 23 bits, you could create an array of bits (either with `vector<bool>` or with `bitset`) and access the right multiple of 23 into that array to get to the "object".

Comment: Odds are this gets padded out to a 32-bit type internally though.

Comment: Note:  This does not guarantee that the processor or platform will only use 23 bits.

Comment: A bitfield is not a type in and of itself.  The `struct` containing it is a type, but its representation will be larger than 23 bits.

Comment: I would say correct here, it represents 23 bits, it will be padded to 32 or 64, but so will any type?

Comment: I see all very interesting things to think about, The padding would be an issue. I was wondering if it was possible to use for compressing/uncompressing files under 10MB, thanks @jxh